# issues for NuGet after migrating a c# project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

i'm trying to migrate a project into my visual studio 2012.

On the Manage NuGet Packages, I have this issue:

"Some NuGet Packages are missing from this solution. Click to restore from your online package sources"... but when i click on the restore button, it appears this issue:

"an error occurred while trying to restore packages: Unable to find version '4.1.0-alpha-121112' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi'. "

i'm using .NET Framework 4

How can i solve?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that version '4.1.0-alpha-121112' of package [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/) does not exist on NuGet.org. It is not available on [MyGet](https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetwebstacknightly) from the ASP.NET Web Stack Nightly package source either. So NuGet cannot restore it since it is no longer available.

Looking at [Symbol Source](http://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost/4.1.0-alpha-121112) it looks like this NuGet package was at one point available from the ASP.NET Web Stack Nightly package source on MyGet but it no longer seems to be available. I suspect they have deleted the old packages from that MyGet package source.

Unless you can find the original NuGet package, you will either have to manually remove the NuGet package reference, by editing the project file and packages.config file, and reinstall a version that exists.

Comment: Thanks Matt, could you describe how can i remove the NuGet package reference, and how to edit that files? And which version of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi can I install?

Comment: You can edit the packages.config file and remove the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi reference. Also edit the .csproj and remove anything that references files from the packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.4.1.0-alpha-121112 directory. You will probably have other problems since Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi depends on other alpha NuGet packages which may have disappearred from NuGet. I would probably look at installing Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 4.0.30506 which is the closest. If your original project did compile I would look at using the original NuGet packages and copy them into your NuGet cache.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you upgrade to the latest NuGet.

2) Make sure you're doing package restore "The Right Way" http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html

That should resolve the issue.

if still this ain't solve you can see this [Rightway to migrate](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/migrate-away-from-msbuild-based-nuget-package-restore)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but nothing happens!!! The project that i'm trying to migrate contains a .negut folder in "MyProject/yui.compressor"folder. if i remove that, it'll won't open the project in vs2012, because in the *.csproj there is this line:  "<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />". How can I solve the issue? i'm going crazy!!!